# Describe an event that will be held at a time other than its standard one

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, idiom-requests

How to describe an event that is usually held in a specific time-frame but this time and based on the extraordinary conditions should be held at another time?

Specifically, FIFA World Cup usually held in June, but its 2022 version, due to high summer temperature  in Qatar, should be held in Winter. So, is there any phrase/term for describing such an event?

Comment: [Extraordinary](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/egm.asp)

Answer (score 2):

The event is ***rescheduled***. *Reschedule* means

> change the time of (a planned event).
>
> - The concert has been ***rescheduled*** for September. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=reschedule%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB976GB976&sxsrf=ALiCzsZJkcqAxdh2N7pz36MR8NGqew0-EQ%3A1660671255073&ei=F9X7YsGJBOLD8gK_6a-AAg&oq=reschedule%20me&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYATIFCAAQkQIyCAgAELEDEJECMgUIABCRAjIFCAAQkQIyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6BAgjECc6BAgAEEM6BwgjEOoCECc6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToQCAAQgAQQhwIQsQMQgwEQFDoKCC4QsQMQ1AIQQzoOCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEQyQM6BQgAEJIDOggIABCABBCxAzoRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQrwFKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQ4ANY_iBgvC1oAnAAeACAAX6IAYsMkgEEMy4xMZgBAKABAbABCsgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz))

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). I was aware about this word (and it was better to mention that in the OP) but looking for something a bit idiomatic or wordy.

Answer (score 0):

You already have **prepone** and **postpone**

Then you have **reschedule** as mentioned by @fev

You can also say the same thing in a different way, such as

- Move around (the dates) or Move (the dates) around
- Reassign (the dates)
- Chop and change (the dates)